# Add custom top 10 list to woocommerce country dropdown

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, dropdown, country

Hope to find a solution here.

I'd like to add a **custom top-10 country list** to the woocommerce (checkout) country dropdown list. So it should look like:

**Top 10 countries**
Netherlands
Germany
Belgium
UK
USA

**Select your country**
*normal list*

I couldn't find any a filter for this, only to add one or more countries.

Comment: What have you tried so far... please show your code and post the problem rather than asking for prepared solution

Comment: @mhasan: I tried things like this, but it only adds a country:

function woo_add_my_country( $country ) {
   $country["AE-DU"] = 'Dubai';
   return $country;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_add_my_country', 10, 1 );

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_sort_countries', '__return_false');
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'change_country_order_in_checkout_form'     );
    function change_country_order_in_checkout_form($countries)
{
    $usa = $countries['US']; // Store the data for "US" key
    $uk = $countries['GB']; // Store the data for "UK" key

    // Return "US" and "UK" first in the countries array
    return array('US' => $usa, 'GB' => $uk) + $countries;
}
```

However, this removes the countries from the main list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tray like this.
This is working correctly for me.

https://www.wpstud.io/add-custom-select-field-woocommerce-checkout-page/

Comment: This is a solution for adding a custom field to the checkout. What I am searching for is a way to order existing countries in the country-dropdown-list to a top-10-list.